# How to fully sync local repository using Mercurial (bitbucket)

Tags: repository, version-control, mercurial

I'm new to VCS and I decided to give Mercurial a try. I signed up for bitbucket and created some repositories. The I created `/home/max/hgrepo/` and ran `hg clone http://bitbucket.org/[username]/[repository]`

That made a `[repository]` directory. I copied some source files into this directory. then I `hg add`, `hg commit` and `hg push`. Then I wanted to move my source files into a `src` directory instead of having them into the root dir. So I moved all the sources files down one directory to my `src` directory. I then ran `hg add *`, then `hg commit` and lastly `hg push`.

The problem I have is that the old sources files in the root directory of my repo are still there. How do I remove them? I don't have them in my local repo anymore. Is there a way to fully sync my local repository and my remote one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `addremove` command to mark missing files (those prefaced with a `!`) as removed.

See the excellent [Mercurial: the Definitive Guide](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/mercurial-in-daily-use.html) chapter on tracking files.

For future reference, there is a command to move files, `hg mv`.

Comment: I didn't know about `hg move`, thanks. I'll have a look at the guide.